# Install Antivirus on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, anti-virus

So, I have a `CIS Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 - Level 1` image that needs to have an Anti-Virus installed and set to scan every day.  This must be done with PowerShell so I can fit it into the packer script or CloudFormation Init.  I chose Microsoft Security Essentials because it's free, but I'm happy to consider other free AV's if they're easier to setup.

This CIS image is basically a hardened version of Windows that locks all the permissions down and hides vulnerabilities.  It may be causing some of the issues I'm experiencing.

This is the script I have so far:

```
.\MSEInstall.exe /s /runwgacheck /o
Start-Sleep 5 # I have no idea how to wait for the installer to finish
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scan" 
ScheduleDay "0"
```

Unfortunately, I get:

```
Set-ItemProperty : Requested registry access is not allowed.
```

I'm already running powershell with administrator privileges.  Otherwise, I wouldn't be able to install the AV.  I can get the value just fine, and I can edit the key manually with `regedit` just fine.

Some other article said something about ACLs, and true enough, `regedit` shows that the Admin group doesn't have full access to the folder.  It had me try:

```
$user = whoami
$regPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scan"
$key = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine.OpenSubKey($regPath, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck]::ReadWriteSubTree,[System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights]::ChangePermissions)
$acl = $key.GetAccessControl()
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule ($user,"FullControl","Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
$key.SetAccessControl($acl)
```

But I just get:

```
Exception calling "OpenSubKey" with "3" argument(s): "Requested registry access is not allowed.
```

So I'm stuck.  Does anyone have any recommendations on how to get any free AV installed and running every day through Powershell?

Comment: You need to change the owner before you can change the permissions.

Comment: @GregAskew, understandable.  I followed a guide to change it, but the administrator user doesn't have permissions to change the owner to itself.  Any suggestions?  https://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/powershell/set-registry-key-owner/